# Loop, aggregate and return unique DataRow sum

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a DataGrid which contains multiple transactions of Customer's buy ins.
What I want is to add up the transaction buy ins from each customer and add the result on the related images. What I have at the moment gives me logic errors i.e. adding the same amounts on more than one images.

Here is the structure of my DataGrid (column titles): `[Name,Surname, Buyin, Type, StartTime, TransactionID, CustomerID]`
and here is my code:

```
Dim tbActivePlayers As DataTable = Me.ActivePlayersTableAdapter.GetData()

Dim tbTemp As New DataTable

'   table = DataSet.Tables("Orders")

' Declare an object variable.
Dim objTotalBuyin As Object
Dim iCount, ilbl As Integer
ilbl = 1

Dim viewUniquePlayers As New DataView(tbActivePlayers)
Dim iActivePlayers As Integer = viewUniquePlayers.ToTable(True, "CustomerID").Rows.Count
Dim dtDataTable As DataTable = viewUniquePlayers.ToTable(True, "CustomerID")

Dim myLabel As Label
For iCount = 0 To dtDataTable.Rows.Count
    objTotalBuyin = tbActivePlayers.Compute("Sum(Buyin)", "CustomerID = " & tbActivePlayers.Rows(iCount).Item("CustomerID"))
    'MsgBox("Name: " & tbActivePlayers.Rows(iCount + 1).Item("Name") & ", Sumbuyin:" & sumObject.ToString & " ResultCount:" & ResultCount)
    '
    myLabel = CType(Me.Controls.Find("lblPlayer" & ilbl, True)(0), Label)
    If Not myLabel Is Nothing Then
        myLabel.Text = "Empty Seat"
    End If
    '

    myLabel.Text = tbActivePlayers.Rows(iCount).Item("Name") & Environment.NewLine & _
                   "€" & objTotalBuyin.ToString

    myLabel.Image = Global.PokerBusiness.My.Resources.Resources.seatocc
    ilbl += 1

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter function for the `Compute` seems to be based off each row in `tbActivePlayers`, yet you're looping over each row (and thus counting the rows of) a view of unique players.  My brain compiler tells me this might well be the source of your logic errors, because you're potentially computing your sum with a filter that's using a single, unique customer ID more than once.  Consider changing

```
objTotalBuyin = tbActivePlayers.Compute("Sum(Buyin)", "CustomerID = " & tbActivePlayers.Rows(iCount).Item("CustomerID"))
```

To

```
objTotalBuyin = tbActivePlayers.Compute("Sum(Buyin)", "CustomerID = " & dtDataTable.Rows(iCount).Item("CustomerID"))
```

Comment: Thanks adrian. The thing is I have tried that too. I have added another column like this: Dim dtDataTable As DataTable = viewUniquePlayers.ToTable(True, "CustomerID", -> "Name") and I refer to the name and now it works. Thanks again.